# Android client and C# server can not connect

Tags: c#, android, sockets, server

This is the android client code:

```
Button btn1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Tocket.start();
        }
    });
}
private Thread Tocket = new Thread(){
    public void Run(){
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket("Correct server_ip", 10004);
            PrintWriter out;
            out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
            out.write("request");
            out.flush();

        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("ClientActivity", "S: Error", e);
        }
    }
};
```

And this is the server code:

```
    private Socket server;
    private Socket client;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Text == "ON") return;

        this.Text = "ON";
        server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        MessageBox.Show(Get_MyIP());
        server.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 10004));
        server.Listen(20);

        new Thread(delegate()
        {
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    client = server.Accept();
                    Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                    {
                        richTextBox1.Text += client.LocalEndPoint + "has been connected\r\n";
                    });

                    new Thread(delegate()
                    {
                        while (true)
                        {
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                            try
                            {
                                client.Receive(buffer);
                                string unde_buffer_string = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer).Replace("\0", "");
                                if (unde_buffer_string.Length > 0)
                                {
                                    Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                                    {
                                        richTextBox1.Text += client.LocalEndPoint + " send :" + unde_buffer_string + "\r\n";
                                    });
                                }
                                else if (!client.Connected && unde_buffer_string.Length == 0)
                                {
                                    client.Disconnect(true);
                                }
                            }
                            catch (Exception)
                            {
                            }
                            finally
                            {
                                client.Close();
                            }
                        }
                    }).Start();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                });
            }
        }).Start();
    }
```

The client code is in android java and server code is in C#. But I can't connect both.

I've added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` in androidmanifest.xml and set the adb local port setting.

There is no other problem, but the android client is not connecting.
I can see the "client not ready yet" message. Debugging on virtual device, both android devices are not working.

Comment: `"Correct server_ip"`. Well sorry. I doubt that. Please tell exactly the used ip. And you did not tell if the android client is on device or emulator.

Comment: `"client not ready yet" message. `??? There is no such message text in your code.